# How to use vyper's external_interface in brownie?

Tags: brownie, interfaces, vyper

An external interface can be generated by `vyper` as such:

```
vyper -f external_interface contracts/CurveCryptoSwap.vy
```

Doing that results in the following output:

```
# External Interfaces
interface Curvecryptoswap:
    def __default__(): payable
    def price_oracle(k: uint256) -> uint256: view
    def price_scale(k: uint256) -> uint256: view
    def last_prices(k: uint256) -> uint256: view
    ...
```

But where exactly does this go? [Vyper's documentation on external interfaces](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interfaces.html#extracting-interfaces) states:

> The output can then easily be copy-pasted to be consumed.

I tried saving it to `<brownie_project>/interfaces/ICurveCryptoSwap.vy` but brownie does not see it...

```
>>> from brownie import interface
>>> pool = interface.Curvecryptoswap(...)
AttributeError: 'InterfaceContainer' object has no attribute 'Curvecryptoswap'
```

All this is no problem when using `vyper -f abi`, but the resulting JSON file is just so messy; the external interface provides much cleaner code to read.

Comment: My working import (which you helped me accomplish) is `import interfaces.ifoo as IFoo`.  Do you need to import your generated file with the relative path: `import interfaces.ICurveCryptoSwap`?  I'm not a Python dev, so I'm discovering its import syntax by trial-and-error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps described in the question are correct:

```
$ vyper -f external_interface contracts/Contract.vy
```

output:

```
# External Interfaces
interface Contract:
    def __default__(): payable
```

save this to a file in the interfaces folder, eg `interfaces/IContract.vy`. it can then be called in brownie (console) through:

```
>>> contract = interface.IContract(address)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to paste my `Foo` interface definition into my `Bar` contract.  Otherwise I got a runtime error from `Foo` saying it doesn't know anything about `Foo`'s method `baz()`.

Having interface `Foo` defined in its own file and importing it into contract `Bar` compiled fine, but failed at runtime when calling `Foo.baz()`.

I also had to put my `Foo` interface definition file into Brownie's `contracts` directory.  At first, I tried putting it in the `interfaces` directory, but the compiler couldn't find it.

I'm using Brownie 1.19.2 and Vyper 0.3.7, on macos.

Comment: i believe the answer to your problem is actually solved here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/129781/interfaces-not-working-in-vyper

Comment: @gosuto You're right. Thanks:-)  Now my interface import works!  No need to copy paste interface code into my contract.