# Interfaces not working in vyper

Tags: vyper

I have the following interface in it's own file:

```py
# @version ^0.3.3

interface IFace:
  def read_stuff() -> uint256: view
```

And I'd like to import it into my other contract.

```py
# @version ^0.3.3
import interfaces.IFace as IFace

@external
@view
def read_contract(some_address: address) -> uint256:
    myContract: IFace = IFace(some_address)
    return myContract.read_stuff()
```

However, in doing so, I get an error when compiling:

```
Error compiling: contracts/MyContract.vy
vyper.exceptions.UnknownAttribute: IFace has no member 'read_stuff'. 
  contract "contracts/MyContract.vy", function "read_contract", line 9:11 
       8     myContract: IFace = IFace(some_address)
  ---> 9     return myContract.read_stuff()
  ------------------^
      10
```

What's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Imported interfaces](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interfaces.html?highlight=interface#importing-interfaces) use a different syntax.

When importing an interface, the syntax you use is like a regular vyper contract. Update your interface as such:

```py
# @version ^0.3.3
@view
@external
def read_stuff() -> uint256: 
    pass
```